# Run model on each group in dataframe and output key metrics into new dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, model

I have a the following [model](/questions/tagged/model) that I currently run for one state of data.  It's code from this blog:  https://blog.ephorie.de/epidemiology-how-contagious-is-novel-coronavirus-2019-ncov

It models future infections based on existing daily COVID-19 infections data.  I have a dataset for all US counties and want to run the same analysis county by county and output key variables into a dataset for each county.  Here is the code I ran for one state.

```
library(deSolve)
library(tidyverse)

date <- c('2020-03-24','2020-03-25','2020-03-26','2020-03-24','2020-03-25','2020-03-26')
fips <- c(1001,1001,1001,1002,1002,1002)
Infected <- c(1,2,4,4,7,9)
day <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
N <- c(55601,55601,55601,2231,2231,2231)

cp <- data.frame(date,fips,Infected,day,N)
```

And the [model](/questions/tagged/model):

```
SIR <- function(time, state, parameters) {
    par <- as.list(c(state, parameters))
    with(par, {
        dS <- -beta/N * I * S
        dI <- beta/N * I * S - gamma * I
        dR <- gamma * I
        list(c(dS, dI, dR))
    })
}

init <- c(S = N-Infected[1], I = Infected[1], R = 0)
RSS <- function(parameters) {
    names(parameters) <- c("beta", "gamma")
    out <- ode(y = init, times = Day, func = SIR, parms = parameters)
    fit <- out[ , 3]
    sum((Infected - fit)^2)
}

Opt <- optim(c(0.5, 0.5), RSS, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(0, 0), upper = c(1, 1))
Opt_par <- setNames(Opt$par, c("beta", "gamma"))
t <- 1:365 # time in days
fit <- data.frame(ode(y = init, times = t, func = SIR, parms = Opt_par))
R0 <- setNames(Opt_par["beta"] / Opt_par["gamma"], "R0")
infections <- fit[fit$I == max(fit$I), "I", drop = FALSE]
deaths <- max(fit$I) * 0.02
```

Here is a small sample of dataset I have with county level data:

```
date <- '2020-03-24','2020-03-25','2020-03-26','2020-03-24','2020-03-25','2020-03-26'
fips <- 1001,1001,1001,1002,1002,1002
Infected <- 1,2,4,4,7,9
day <- 1,2,3,1,2,3
N <- 55601,55601,55601,2231,2231,2231
```

I'd like to run the above model for each fips (county code).  As output, I want to have a [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) that includes: 
`time_stamp`, `fips`, `max(Infected)`, `max(day)`, `N`, `beta`, `gamma`, `R0`, `infections`, `deaths`

I'd like a [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) pipe solution and have tried using `group_modify()` but continually get an error.  Can you help??

Here is what I have and the error I get:

```
SIR <- function(time, state, parameters) {
    par <- as.list(c(state, parameters))
    with(par, {
        dS <- -beta/N * I * S
        dI <- beta/N * I * S - gamma * I
        dR <- gamma * I
        list(c(dS, dI, dR))
    })
}

RSS <- function(parameters) {
    names(parameters) <- c("beta", "gamma")
    out <- ode(y = c(S, I, R)
               , times = Day, func = SIR, parms = parameters)
    fit <- out[ , 3]
    sum((Infected - fit)^2)
}

cp <- cp %>%
    group_by(fips) %>%
    mutate(S = N-Infected[1], I = Infected[1], R = 0) %>%
    group_modify(optim(c(0.5, 0.5), RSS, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(0, 0), upper = c(1, 1)))
```

Error:

Error in ode(y = c(S, I, R), times = Day, func = SIR, parms = parameters) : 
  object 'S' not found

Comment: Can you add the `error message` that you're getting, here?

Comment: thanks massisenergy.  A added it.  I think my approach is wrong, I'm just not sure how to run/call the functions within my piped commands.

Comment: Your call for mutate should be like `mutate(df)` where `df` is a `dataframe` or `datatable`. So, `mutate(init)` would be an example of the right usage. Type `?mutate` & hit enter in you `RStudio` console.

Comment: Hi, I tried your model and found several problems. Lets start with the first one: Your model SIR contains a variable "N" that is no state variable. What is this? Is it just S or is it S+I+R? See also https://github.com/tpetzoldt/covid for a similar model.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to write a separate function, e.g. `fit_model` that is then called by `group_modify`. Note that I had to change some other parts and that there are already more complex models available for this problem. The github page mentioned above, contains some links.

```
library(deSolve)
library(tidyverse)

cp <- data.frame(
  date     = c('2020-03-24','2020-03-25','2020-03-26','2020-03-24','2020-03-25','2020-03-26'),
  fips     = c(1001,1001,1001,1002,1002,1002),
  Infected = c(1,2,4,4,7,9),
  day      = c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
  N        = c(55601,55601,55601,2231,2231,2231)
)

SIR <- function(time, state, parameters) {
  par <- as.list(c(state, parameters))
  with(par, {
    N  <- S + I + R
    dS <- -beta/N * I * S
    dI <- beta/N * I * S - gamma * I
    dR <- gamma * I
    list(c(dS, dI, dR))
  })
}

RSS <- function(parameters, init, data) {
  names(parameters) <- c("beta", "gamma")
  out <- ode(y = init,
             times = data$day, func = SIR, parms = parameters)
  fit <- out[ , 3]
  sum((data$Infected - fit)^2)
}

fit_model <- function(data) {
  init <- slice(data, 1) %>% select(S, I, R) %>% unlist()
  opt <- optim(c(0.5, 0.5), RSS,
               init = init,
               data = data,
               method = "L-BFGS-B",
               lower = c(0, 0),
               upper = c(1, 1))

  data.frame(alpha=opt$par[1], beta=opt$par[2], RSS=opt$value,
             conv= opt$convergence, ok = opt$convergence == 0)
}

cp %>%
  group_by(fips) %>%
  mutate(S = N[1]-Infected[1], I = Infected[1], R = 0) %>%
  group_modify( ~ fit_model(.))
```